# SoapUI - How to disable ssl keystore for a test

Tags: ssl, soapui

I'm trying to run a REST call test case in SoapUI, and I need an ssl keystore - certificate verificaton for all the tests except one where I check if it rejects calls without a cert.

Is there a way to disable the cert with setup scripts or any other way without removing it from the ssl preferences for that test only?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is via the following groovy code:
testRunner.testCase.testSteps['Step Name'].testRequest.setSslKeystore(new EmptyWssCrypto())
(Source: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/API-Functional-Security-Testing/Set-SSL-Keystore-using-Groovy-on-Test-Step-level/td-p/195889)

You can also do it by setting your Keystore on a project level (double-click on your project -> Click on Tab WS-Security Configurations -> Click on Keystore -> Click "+" and choose Keystore)
[image: WS-Security Config]

If this is set up you can choose between Keystores for each Request on your "Request Properties" at the bottom left:
[image: Request Properties]

So if you don´t pick any Keystore here it should lead to the behaviour you are looking for.